# Is the 2.4MB Wubi Installer blocked in China?

Tags: installation, wubi, downloads

Using an existing Wubi will download all the files successfully, however the OS will be unable to install because of bad files. Is the mirror site of Ubuntu installation files GFWed in China?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in China and you tried to download Ubuntu from the Main Servers, you may get a corrupted copy because the servers are usually located in the US or the UK.

It is possible that the GFW can block the servers, though.  So I would suggest you to download from the [cn99](http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu-releases/12.04/) mirror in China and do a full install with the official Ubuntu Image.

32-bit CD: [ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso](http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu-releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso)

64-bit CD: [ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu-releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

Wubi:  [wubi.exe](http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu-releases/12.04/wubi.exe)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

### Try Installing From a Full Ubuntu `.iso`

You can download a full Ubuntu `.iso` image and install Wubi from that (either by burning it to a CD/DVD or USB flash drive and reading it from that, or by mounting the image in Windows). This may work if `Wubi.exe`, downloaded by itself, cannot retrieve good files.

### Try Downloading a Current `wubi.exe` (Or `.iso` Image) From a Different Mirror

There are a number of different mirrors from which the Wubi installer, or full `.iso` images, can be downloaded. It is *possible* that *some* of them are [blocked in the PRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_firewall_of_china#Technical_implementation). If this is the case, you should be able to download the software by using a different mirror, or perhaps by using the main download site. There is [a list of mirrors at the bottom of this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads). And [this is the main download site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

If you need more detailed help picking the right file from any mirror or the main site, please comment to let me know and I can expand this answer further (based on the specific assistance you request).

### Provide More Detailed Information

Alternatively, please **edit your question** to include the complete and exact text of any error messages. Only with that information could a solution more specific to your situation likely be provided.